# How to align RIGHT the content of TextArea in LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textarea

I want to align the text in a `TextArea` to the right. I tried the following code:

```
     Form form = new Form();
     TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Some Arabic text ...");
     textArea.setRTL(true);
     textArea.setAlignment(RIGHT);
     form.addComponent(textArea);
```

The result was just moving the scroll to left, 
But the text is still not aligned `RIGHT`, 
check the image below:

[image]

So how to align the content to the `RIGHT` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may sound crazy for the first instance :) but setting the alignment to `TextArea.LEFT` solved the issue and now it's `RIGHT` aligned !

```
    Form form = new Form();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Some Arabic text ...");
    textArea.setRTL(true);
    textArea.setAlignment(TextArea.LEFT);
    form.addComponent(textArea);
```

Setting it to `LEFT` makes the displayed text `RIGHT` aligned !

**Or** by removing the `textArea.setRTL(true)` which is mirroring the display

```
    Form form = new Form();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Some Arabic text ...");
    textArea.setAlignment(TextArea.RIGHT);
    form.addComponent(textArea);
```

---

For those who are interested in **more complicated details** when it's set to RTL:
the `paint` method of `TextArea` class is

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().drawTextArea(g, this);
}
```

And `drawTextArea` method in `DefaultLookAndFeel` is as follows:

```
int align = ta.getAbsoluteAlignment();
// remaining code is here in initial source
switch(align) {
     case Component.RIGHT:
          x = ta.getX() + ta.getWidth() - rightPadding - f.stringWidth(displayText);
          break;
     // remaining code is here in initial source
}
g.drawString(displayText, x, y);
```

Unfortunately `TextArea.RIGHT` value is 3 
But when calling `ta.getAbsoluteAlignment()` it returns 1 (despite that the object's alignment is set by code to `TextArea.RIGHT` !!)
Meanwhile `TextArea.Left` value is 1
That's why it matched the value in the switch and was aligned to `RIGHT`

BTW, if you set

```
textArea.setAlignment(Component.RIGHT);
```

it will also be wrong, because `Component.RIGHT` outside the paint method has the value 3 not 1 !

Comment: As you are activating **RTL** for your `TextArea` the directions of the text rendering is reversed hence Left is considered as Right. I would suggest you to get clarification on this from Shai by filling a post @ [LWUIT Java Form](http://www.java.net/forums/mobile-embedded/lwuit). And thus contribute to the LWUIT community.

Comment: Vimal is correct. It sounds odd but it makes sense once you think about it. When you activate bidi you are effectively reversing the display by default so right becomes left and east becomes west... That makes sense in RTL applications since in those applications 99% of the UI components would want to do the exact opposite of the English version, hence you can write an English UI and localize it to bidi by just translating and flipping the bidi switch.

Comment: Yup, it can be done just by removing this line of code in my initial post:  **textArea.setRTL(true);** and the remainig as it is. Thanks for this valuable comment !

Comment: BTW, I think RIGHT and LEFT shouldn't being reversed, this is very ambiguous in terminology, especially with those who come from other APIs backgrounds. Instead of this, I think the RTL flag should auto set the alignment layout to RIGHT unless the code specifies otherwise, this will avoid mis-using the terms. Left should remain left as its name same for right. Thanks so much for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You only have to write 'TextArea.RIGHT' instead of 'RIGHT'

```
textArea.setAlignment(TextArea.RIGHT);
```

Comment: I've tried TextArea.RIGHT, unfortunately still the text is left aligned (BTW, even the text is English, it's left aligned) !

Comment: Check my answer in the same discussion thread, the solution is totally insane :) thanks so much for your try to help, i'll mark it up :)

Comment: TextArea.RIGHT is Component.RIGHT they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line:

```java
TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Some Arabic text ...");
textArea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```